# Pull some data from a site but I keep getting an TypeError

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, typeerror

Here is the script below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/government-bonds/us"
x = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
tbl= soup.find('table', {'id': 'table class'})
```

I keep getting this error and I can't figure out how to get around it.
x = requests.get(url)

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: are you at any point in your program creating a variable/constant called `str`?

Comment: Aparrently I upgraded my Python to the latest (3.9.6) and now the error is not happening anymore... I was due for an upgrade anyways..

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

You try to call text on your `url`, that is still a `string`:

```
soup= BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
```

#### How to fix?

What you really wanna do is call text on your response, that is assaigned to `x`

```
soup= BeautifulSoup(x.text, "html.parser")
```

**Note** *Take a look into your soup - You won't get the table that way - Please make sure your browser supports JavaScript and cookies and that you are not blocking them from loading. For more information you can review our Terms of Service **To solve this challenge [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) please***

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/government-bonds/us"
x = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(x.text, "html.parser")

soup
```